# How to get the inner frame in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, frames

I was building a simplistic "game" as sort of tutorial into developing apps or such in java.
My `Main` class `extends JFrame`. It was just moving a ball around the screen. After getting to the point where I can move the ball can move I started implementing collision with the boundaries of the window and spent several minutes trying to figure out why the only went some beyond the border on 3 sides and then far beyond the top before I realized that the boundaries were being obeyed but that they were the edges of the actual window, beyond the display area.

How would I set up the `Main` class so that the boundaries are the visible area? Would it extend a different class? And then what it be inside of something else?

Answer (score 1):

- It's hard to say what you may be doing wrong without code,
- but for one thing, you should never be drawing directly in the JFrame and should avoid extending JFrame.
- Instead extend JPanel, get it's boundaries, and draw in this JPanel.
- Also, make sure to override the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method,
- to also call the `super.paintComponent(g)` inside the override.
- Put the JPanel into a JFrame for display.
- Make sure to check out the Swing drawing tutorials before doing this coding because often you have to change basic assumptions when doing graphics program and especially animation programs.

Comment: Do the listeners need to be placed on the JFrame because I have them on the Main extends JPanel and it wasn't working

Comment: @DoubleMx2: What listeners? And "wasn't working" tells us little. The only way to tell why anything isn't working is to study code and to debug.

Comment: Well, I had a KeyListener attached to the JFrame in order to receive keyboard input, and when I changed Main to extend JPanel I left the KeyListener on the JPanel. However the JPanel didn't seem toreceive any keypress notification. The KeyListener worked when it was attached to the JFrame, but not the JPanel.

Comment: @DoubleMx2 you will want to change that since as a rough rule you should avoid KeyListeners with Swing, but that should likely be the subject of a different question on this site. Your main question has been answered: don't draw inside a JFrame or other top level window. Use a JPanel instead.